# VB.net FindByValue not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here is my code:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    If DD_SalesCounselor.Items.FindByValue(dr("Sales_Id_Fk").ToString) Is Nothing     Then
         Me.DD_SalesCounselor.SelectedValue = "-1"
     Else 
         Me.DD_SalesCounselor.SelectedValue = dr("Sales_Id_Fk")
     End If
End If
```

It is on the Page_Load event.  Goes to -1 every time...but the value is in the dropdown?  Any ideas?

Comment: you might want to add the appropriate asp or whatever tag to attract the correct attention.  3 mins to format the code would help too

Comment: Hello CemCoder, welcome to StackOverflow - can you post your actual source code

Answer (score 2):

During the Load event, the values are not yet available.  You either need to put the values directly out the of Response stream or waiting until after the databinding event.

Comment: Solved!!!  I put it under Page_SaveStateComplete  and it worked like a charm.  Thanks Marc